# How do I declare a variable length array and initialize it to zero?

Tags: c, arrays

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int arr[n];
arr[n]={0};
```

I want to initialize all elements to 0.

on compilation i get error "expected expression" at line 4 position 8.

I searched but found no method to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

`arr[n]={0};`

you need to (assuming automatic variables)

in definition (assuming `n` is a constant expression):

```
int arr[n] = {0,};
```

or after definition

```
memset(arr, 0, n * sizeof(*arr));
```

or

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) arr[i] = 0;
```

if `n` is  a constant expression and the `arr` has static storage duration (is global or has static keyword `before` it) you do not have to do anything

Comment: VLAs can't be initialized.

Comment: @usr was a bit imprecise

Comment: VLAs must be either on stack or on heap; either way, you have to use `memset()`.

Comment: unless they are not VLAs (note the const expresion remark)

Answer (score 4):

VLAs (variable length arrays) can't be initialized.

You can instead use `memset`:

```
memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);
```

Alternatively, you can use a fixed size array (e.g. `int arr[25] = {0};`) or dynamically allocated array (e.g. with `calloc` that zero initializes).

Answer (score 0):

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
> ...
> **Constraints**
> ...
> 3     The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete
> object type *that is not a variable length array type.*

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.  VLAs may not have an initializer as part of their definition.  You will have to zero out the array after the declaration, either using `memset` or a loop as shown by others.